# Python "Cannot call 'anonym_function_2"

Tags: python, function, return, arguments, trigonometry

I am not developer, so my question is probably ridiculous. I have an error (see the message below) for the two lines starting by `sum1` `sum2`.

Code:

```py
#Get single constituent sinusoid on z
sx(i, k, N) =>
    sum1 = ReX_(k)*cos(2*pi*k*i/N)
    sum2 = ImX_(k)*sin(2*pi*k*i/N)
    return = sum1+sum2
```

Error:

> Cannot call 'anonym_function_2' with arguments (fun_arg__, fun_arg__, fun_arg__, series[float]);

Can you tell me if there is a syntax error?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are writing in Pine then it is not helpful to put Python in the title and the tags. This is not a question about Python.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to write must have a proper indentation for a python interpreter. Second thing is to have proper keywords like `def` for function declaration, and `return sum1+sum2`not `return =sum1+sum2` to return from a within a function.

Here is the correct pseudo code that will help you understand code syntax.

```
def sx(i, k, N): 
  sum1 = ReX_(k)*cos(2*pi*k*i/N)
  sum2 = ImX_(k)*sin(2*pi*k*i/N)
  return sum1+sum2
```

Can you please define `ReX_` and `ImX_`?

Comment: I m using Pine by the way ;)

Comment: what is Pine? never hear of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not working with return sum1+sum2 :s => 'return' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration

```
//Real part of the Frequency Domain Representation
ReX(k) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i=0 to N-1
        sum := sum + z[i]*cos(2*pi*k*i/N)
    return = sum

//Imaginary part of the Frequency Domain Representation
ImX(k) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i=0 to N-1
        sum := sum + z[i]*sin(2*pi*k*i/N)
    return = -sum

//Get sinusoidal amplitude from frequency domain  
ReX_(k) =>
    case = 0.0
    if(k!=0 and k!=N/2)
        case := 2*ReX(k)/N
    if(k==0)
        case := ReX(k)/N
    if(k==N/2)
        case := ReX(k)/N
    return = case

 //Get sinusoidal amplitude from frequency domain  
ImX_(k) =>
    return = -2*ImX(k)/N

//Get full Fourier Transform
x(i, N) =>
    sum1 = 0.0
    sum2 = 0.0
    for k=0 to N/2
        sum1 := sum1 + ReX_(k)*cos(2*pi*k*i/N) 
    for k=0 to N/2
        sum2 := sum2 + ImX_(k)*sin(2*pi*k*i/N)
    return = sum1+sum2
```